# Advise on building web components in Shopify dawn theme

Tags: shopify, web-component, shopify-template

I am working on moving the functionality of an existing Shopify theme over to the dawn theme as a base, I want to incorporate the new code in the same pattern as the Dawn theme so it will mean transferring most of the existing code to web components.

I am new to web components so I am basically just looking for some advice or feedback from the first task so I don't make a series of similar mistakes.

The feature is an infinite scroll type load more button for collection pages. It uses the pagination next page liquid object (stored in a data attribute of the custom element) to load the next page products with a fetch request and also updates the data attribute so the next page is loaded.

This was a simple function before but this now seems quite complicated and I was wondering if I have taken the right approach here.

````
{% javascript %}
  class InfiniteScroll extends HTMLUListElement {
    constructor() {
      super();
    }

    connectedCallback() {
      this.productsOnPage = document.querySelector('[is=infinite-scroll]');
      this.loadProductSetHandler = this.onLoadProductSet.bind(this);
      this.loadMoreButton = document.querySelector('.infinite-scroll__load-more-button');
      this.loadMoreSpinner = document.querySelector('.infinite-scroll__load-more .loading-overlay__spinner');
      this.loadMoreButton.addEventListener('click', this.loadProductSetHandler, false);
    }

    disconnectedCallback() {
      this.loadMoreButton.removeEventListener();
    }

    getNextProductSet() {
      return this.productsOnPage.dataset.nextUrl;
    }

    setNextProductSet(nextProductSetUrl) {
      this.productsOnPage.dataset.nextUrl = nextProductSetUrl;
    }

    loadProductSet(nextProductSet) {
      this.productsOnPage.append(...nextProductSet);
      this.loadMoreButton.classList.remove('hidden');
      this.loadMoreSpinner.classList.add('hidden');
    }

    loadingProcess() {
      this.loadMoreButton.classList.add('hidden');
      this.loadMoreSpinner.classList.remove('hidden');
    }

    async fetchNextProductSet() {
      let nextProductSetInfo = {};
      await fetch(this.getNextProductSet())
        .then(function(response) {
          return response.text();
        })
        .then(function(html) {
          let newProductSet = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, "text/html").querySelector('[is=infinite-scroll]');
          nextProductSetInfo = { newProducts: newProductSet.children, nextProductSet: newProductSet.dataset.nextUrl}; 
        })
        .catch(function(err) {  
          console.log('Failed to fetch page: ', err);
        });
      this.setNextProductSet(nextProductSetInfo.nextProductSet);
      this.loadProductSet(nextProductSetInfo.newProducts);
    }

    onLoadProductSet(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      this.loadingProcess();
      this.fetchNextProductSet();
    }
  }

  customElements.define('infinite-scroll', InfiniteScroll, { extends: "ul" });

  {% endjavascript %}```
````

Comment: ``extends HTMLUListElement`` will not work in Safari; Apple has, since 2016, stated they will not implement _Customized Built-In Elements_ There should be a (partial) polyfill around

Comment: You'd think that if infinite scroll was a viable technique for collections, Shopify would natively support it in their theme. The fact that they do not, and absolutely prefer paging throughout should be a tell. Where I have used infinite scroll on Shopify myself, it has always felt like a fragile hack. Not everything needs to be a doom-scrolling machine!

Comment: @DavidLazar hmm maybe, Shopify doesn't support an infinite scroll function as it doesn't really work with their filtering and sorting functions but there are other cases for it when filtering/sorting are not used. We don't actually use it in production but I thought it was an easy one to start using/learning web components.

Comment: I agree that it is a good learning exercise! I did it with React but found the whole experience distasteful and in the end, stuck with paging. Infinite scroll is not a panacea, it is just bling-bling.